# ImportError: No module named re

Tags: python, androidviewclient

I failed at setting up [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient). It's a tool for Android testing, I want to run a Script (check-import.py) which start with:

```
#! /usr/bin/env monkeyrunner
'''
Created on Aug 29, 2012

@author: diego
'''

import re
import sys
import os
```

but fails with

```
  File "/home/asc/AndroidViewClient/AndroidViewClient/examples/check-import.py", line 8, in <module>
    import re
ImportError: No module named re

130617 20:04:31.907:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.core.Py.ImportError(Py.java:304)
130617 20:04:31.907:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.core.imp.import_first(imp.java:755)
130617 20:04:31.907:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.core.imp.import_module_level(imp.java:837)
130617 20:04:31.907:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:917)
```

Monkeyrunner is part of the Android SDK and, as far as I understand it, can be used as an alternative Python interpreter. It is in my path and runs fine from the command line, python is installed. I tried this on different linux installations. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596653/trying-to-run-simple-monkeyrunner-python-script-importerror-no-module-named-os ?

Comment: I assume you have Android SDK Tools 22.0.1, then, how are you running check-import.py?

Comment: I had an older SDK, using 22.0.1 solved this, thank you both :)